# How to integrate and find the inverse of  $f(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{|1-x|}}, x\in[0,2]$?

Tags: calculus

I need to integrate, then find the inverse.

The function I am working on,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{|1-x|}}, x\in[0,2]$$

I tried to solve it on [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%284%2asqrt%28abs%281-x%29%29). It looks pretty complicated, am I doing this right?  Could I use the [0,2] bounds to make the problem easier?  Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you want to integrate the inverse with bounds $[0,2]$ or integrate $f(x)$ and then find the inverse of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, I would like to integrate with bounds [0,2], and it should integration should sum to 1.  Then find its inverse.  Two separate things.

Comment: Look at my answer. If I am missing something feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break it up into cases. Then you get
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x}}&x<1\\\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x-1}}&x>1\end{cases}$$
Now you can just integrate as normal and get
$$F(x)=\int f(x)dx=\begin{cases}\frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{1-x}+c&x<1\\\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x-1}+c&x>1\end{cases}$$
So to integrate from 0 to 2 you get
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x}}dx+\int_1^2\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x-1}}dx$$
$$=\left[\frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{1-x}\right]_0^1+\left[\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x-1}\right]_1^2=0+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+0=1$$
As for the inverse
$$F^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}1-4x^2&x<1\\1+4x^2&x>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: wow, that looks pretty awesome, thanks!

Comment: @user1061210 No problem! You can accept the answer by clicking the green tick in the top left corner of the answer.

Comment: will do!  Why does wolfram integrator give such a complicated answer?  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%284*sqrt%28abs%281-x%29%29

Comment: My guess is because it does not like piecewise functions and instead puts into one function. This makes it slightly more complicated.

Comment: Should the last line be $$F^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}1-4y^2&x<1\\1+4y^2&x>1\end{cases}$$
Aren't we finding the bounds for y then?  Just wondering.

Comment: You could write the inverse function in terms of y, but then you would get $F^{-1}(y)=\frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{1-y}$ instead.  I just wrote it in terms of x to get $F^{-1}(x)=1-4x^2$. Therefore the bounds are still valid.

Answer (score 0):

1.This function is NOT one to one on the interval $[0,2]$, because $f(1-x)=f(1+x)$, therefore there is no inverse  on $[0,2]$ , consider $f(.5),f(1.5) and f(.9),f(1.1)$ but there are inverses for $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ separately.

2.Draw the funtcion on $[0,2]$, then rotate it 90 degrees, you can see the inverse of the function, and what the integral of the function and it's inverse add up to ( hint adding them up should give you area of a rectangle).

3.Try a simpler function instead, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{4x}$, then try to move up to a function that looks more similar to this one e.g. $f(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: I think the OP was trying to say that s/he wanted to do the inverse after integrating.